# Connecting the dots in order with line

Tags: c#, winforms, list, drawing

I really need some help here. I'm trying to create a program similar to game known as "**connecting the dots**", where you have dots with numbers from (1...n+1) and you need to connect them with lines. 
So I have a panel and I read from the file the coordinates of the dots. But  I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to connect the dots with the lines.

[My current outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Q8Q.png)

---

**To sum up what I want to do:**

- You press on dot 1 , you press on dot 2 and they connect with a line, otherwise they dont connect.
- And you need to conect the dots in order from 1 to n+1.
  I hope you will understand me. Tanks a lot in advance!!

---

```
   private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> pav1;
        pav1 = new List<String>();
        StreamReader datafile = new StreamReader("pav1.txt");

    int[] X = new int[100];
    int[] Y = new int[100];
    int k = 0;
    string line;

    while (datafile.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        line = datafile.ReadLine();
        X[k] = Int16.Parse(line);
        line = datafile.ReadLine();
        Y[k] = Int16.Parse(line);
        k++;
    }
    datafile.Close();
    Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(aBrush, X[i], Y[i], 10, 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawString((i + 1).ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10),
              System.Drawing.Brushes.Gray, new Point(X[i] + 20, Y[i]));
    }

}
```

Comment: Step 1) replace arrays with `List<int>` for more flexibility and create a `List<Point>ListOfPoints` . Step2) Add a `ListOfPoints.Add([new Point(Xk],Y[k]));` Step 3) Add `e.Graphics.DraLines(Pens.Red, ListOfPoints.ToArray()`

Comment: TaW, sorry mate can't quite get what to do there. I can change to the lists but my problem is how to draw the lines and connect the dots. Where I'm stuck

Comment: To draw a line use `Graphics.DrawLine`. To draw several lines use `Graphics.DrawLines`. Also: __reading in the data should happen only once__ or whenever the data __change__, not in the Paint event!!!

Comment: You will also need to code the MouseClick, best using GraphicsPath.IsVisible(e.Location)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, take points out of `panel_paint` method, and add additional property like ordinal. So, instead of arrays X[] and Y[], you should make class like this:

```
public class Dot
{
    public Point Coordinates { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
List<Dot> Dots { get; set; }
```

Make two props for first and second selected dots

```
private Dot FirstDot { get; set; }
private Dot SecondDot { get; set; }
```

Fill that list same way you're filling `X[]` and `Y[]` arrays.

Then add `OnMouseClick` handler on your panel and in it write something like this:

```
    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if user clicked on any of dots in list
        var selectedDot = Dots.FirstOrDefault(dot => e.X < dot.Coordinates.X + 10 && e.X > dot.Coordinates.X
            && e.Y < dot.Coordinates.Y + 10 && e.Y > dot.Coordinates.Y);

        //dot is found, add it to selected first or second dot property
        if (selectedDot != null)
        {
            if (FirstDot == null)
                FirstDot = selectedDot;
            else if (SecondDot == null)
                SecondDot = selectedDot;
        }   

    }
```

now, in your paint method you should check if both dots are set, and if they are, check if they are one next to other, something like

```
if (FirstDot.Ordinal + 1 == SecondDot.Ordinal)
```

then you can draw lines using

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(aBrush, FirstDot.Coordinates, SecondDot.Coordinates);
```

That should be it. I hope you understand the way how to implement it. Apart from few checks, that should be it.

Comment: bear in mind that you will have to save all the lines you already drawn, because paint event is firing every time control is redrawn...

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I managed to do the program. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Graphics.Draw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1(v=vs.110).aspx) method, I don't know why you're using ellipse drawing. And your loop should look something like

```
var myFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
for (int i = 0; i < k; i += 2)
{
    var point1 = new Point(X[i], Y[i]);
    var point2 = new Point(X[i + 1], Y[i + 1]);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(aBrush, point1, point2);
    e.Graphics.DrawString((i + 1).ToString(), myFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Gray, point1);
    e.Graphics.DrawString((i + 2).ToString(), myFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Gray, point2);
}
```

Also, point `0, 0` is the upper left corner.

Comment: The ellispes probably are the dots. For better results (with linewidths>1) connected lines should be drawn in one go with DrawLines.

Comment: Silly me, I misunderstood his question a little. But if he wants to write names of the points, he still has to go with a loop.

Comment: Yes the ellispes are the dots int this case. I did manage to write the names next to the dots, what i didn't manage to do is to connect the dots.

Comment: Yes a loop for the labels and a DrawLines for the connecting lines, (provided they actually can be all drawn in one go!!)

Comment: TaW You need to connect them manually (with mouse) I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear. But I believei I've mencioned, that you connect the dots with mouse. "You press on dot 1 , you press on dot 2 and they connect with a line, otherwise they dont connect." So I can't draw everything at once.